# MySql total is bigger than individual elements

Tags: mysql

I have a huge MySql table that is in use in production. I have tables which are named by geographical areas with foreign keys for smaller divisions. It is structured like db_country-> tbl_city1, tbl_city2, tbl_city3 and each tbl_city has rows for households inside with other details like street, address and number of people for each household.

PROBLEM: If I pull the data for each family grouped by STREETS I get the correct number of people but when I call the number of people in the entire city, I get a slightly inflated number. I know there must be something I've messed up, what is the possible fail area in this scenario?

The first query that yields inflated output is:

```
SELECT sum(people) AS people FROM city WHERE division=2136 AND status=1;
```

and the second query that yields correct output is:

```
SELECT street.name, SUM(people) AS people FROM city INNER JOIN streets
ON city.street=streets.id WHERE division=2136 AND status=1
GROUP BY street.name;
```

The picture is the real output, above table shows combined total(inflated) while the lower one shows individual  streets/villages with the correct number [MYSQL OUTPUT IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fapvy.png)

Comment: so you have separate table for each city? O_O

Comment: Yes I have a separate table for each City and each table contains mostly rows of people with columns being household numbers, street ids, division ids, allocated amount of goods and other demographics.

I spotted the error in Angular Tables as the front end uses Laravel and Angular but upon doing an SQL query I found that the error must be in the DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are records in city table which have no related street record matching the join `city.street=streets.id`.
Try this sql to find out the missed records.

```
Select city.* from city left join street on city.street=streets.id 
WHERE division=2136 AND status=1 where street.id is null.
```

Comment: **SOLVED:**

This ( @amow ) is the solution, I run that query after tuning it to my real table and column names and it showed me 621 entries that had their street ids as 0 while I do not have that id in my streets. The same villages when their sum of goods was queried it gave me 2572 which was the untraceable increase in my original post.

I simply lack enough reputation in this forum but I would have up-voted and marked this as the correct answer.